# How to correctly set the request header in an ajax containing non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: ajax, encoding, request

My HTML file contains a form with just a textarea whose contents are sent to a java servlet (called "Compiler"). The textarea text will always be java code, so it might include characters like +, %, =, etc.
I'm using ajax to get and display the response from the servlet.
But using ajax breaks the whole data being sent by the form, because it strips out part of the text or completely ignores the characters I mentioned above.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function objetoAjax(){
    http_request= false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
           http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
     } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
           http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
           try {
              http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    return http_request;
}

function devolver_resultado(){
    var llamadaAjax = objetoAjax();
    var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
    llamadaAjax.open("POST",'Compiler',true);
    llamadaAjax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(llamadaAjax.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = llamadaAjax.responseText;
        }
    };
    llamadaAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    llamadaAjax.send('codigo='+codigo);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="Compiler" method="post">
    <textarea rows="18" cols="70" id="codigo" name="codigo"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Compile" onclick="devolver_resultado(); return false;">
</form>

<div id="resultado">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've debugged the javascript to see if the problem was where I assign the textarea value to the "codigo" variable:
**var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;**
([screenshot](http://k40.kn3.net/B/6/D/7/B/6/4E1.png))

But this variable is being correctly set, so I suspect the request is being incorrectly encoded ([screenshot](http://k42.kn3.net/F/0/8/C/B/2/059.png)).
I'm new to ajax, but I assume this is controlled by **llamadaAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");**

[From this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) I get that I should encode the form as multipart/form-data. I tried adding the encoding type to the form:  but this didn't help.

So, two questions here:

1) Is actually this line the faulty one? **llamadaAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")**
If so, how do I fix it?

2) If that's not where the bug is, what else could be happening? (remember that removing all the ajax and leaving a plain form that calls my "Compiler" servlet works as expected, so the servlet is not buggy).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

All I needed was to encode the text before sending it:

```
llamadaAjax.send('codigo='+encodeURIComponent(codigo));
```